# Counting NULL values from LEFT OUTER JOIN, is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a question related to joins if anyone can help

I have a query:

```
SELECT cl.*,c.*,s.*,o.*,p.*,r.*
FROM COMPANY_LOCATION__K cl
INNER JOIN COMPANY__K c on c.COMPANY_ID__K = cl.COMPANY_ID__K
INNER JOIN SOCIAL_MEDIA__K s on cl.COMPANY_ID__K = s.COMPANY_ID__K
INNER JOIN OPERATIONAL_HOURS__K o on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = o.LOCATION_ID__K
INNER JOIN PERMISSIONS__K p on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = p.LOCATION_ID__K
LEFT OUTER JOIN REVIEW__K r on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = r.LOCATION_ID__K
ORDER BY DISTANCE__K LIMIT 100;
```

That will list information about a company and many other statistics.

I am running into trouble, because the a `Company_Location` may not necessarily have Reviews associated with it, so when i change the `r.*` to `COUNT(r.rating)`, Rows that don't have reviews aren't being displayed in my result set. I want the Count to come back as `0` so i know that no ratings, exist. is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the actual query you run when you've changed r.* to COUNT(r.rating)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a `group by` to accomplish what you need.  If you want information per company, I think that would be:

```
SELECT cl.*, c.*, s.*, o.*, p.*, count(r.rating)
FROM COMPANY_LOCATION__K cl
INNER JOIN COMPANY__K c on c.COMPANY_ID__K = cl.COMPANY_ID__K
INNER JOIN SOCIAL_MEDIA__K s on cl.COMPANY_ID__K = s.COMPANY_ID__K
INNER JOIN OPERATIONAL_HOURS__K o on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = o.LOCATION_ID__K
INNER JOIN PERMISSIONS__K p on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = p.LOCATION_ID__K
LEFT OUTER JOIN REVIEW__K r on cl.LOCATION_ID__K = r.LOCATION_ID__K
GROUP BY cl.LOCATION_ID
ORDER BY DISTANCE__K
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it is still not showing the rows that have don't have any ratings. @Gordon

Comment: According to the original question, `REVIEW__K` contains the field `rating`.  Nothing in this query is filtering based on this table.  I assume that the company location table is failing to match to another table.  Try putting in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for all the joins.

Comment: Changing them all to outer joins don't seem to work also. However, I did figure it out.. I had to use GROUP BY on the primary key. @Gordon

I used: 
    GROUP BY cl.LOCATION_ID
This is the primary key since a company can possibly have many locations